# What caused, and how to fix, wooden stair tread stains?

Tags: hardwood-floor, hardwood-refinishing

We recently put in brand new, prefinished red oak stair treads. Yesterday we had a steam cleaner come clean the upstairs carpet, and they ran several hoses from their van outside all the way up the stairs. After they left, I noticed these marks on nearly all the treads, running in a fairly straight line about where the hoses were.

I can't think of anything else they would have come from. They don't scrub off, and the finish feels different than on the other parts of the stairs. The white spots are ones I scrubbed, and the dark ones are ones I haven't touched.

What about steam cleaning hoses may have done this?

More importantly, how can we fix them?

[image]

Comment: Did the cleaners use any kind of chemicals, or solely steam (water)?  Could just be water stains.

Comment: Yeah, steam cleaners don't _just_ use steam. They dripped chemicals down your stairs and (presumably) all the way out the door.